# Using history expansion in a bash alias or function

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to make a simple thing to make my teammates lives easier.  They are constantly copying quote into the command line that are formatted which breaks the command ie: “test“ vs. "test"

It's proved surprisingly annoying to do with:

```
function damn() { !!:gs/“/" }
```

or:

```
alias damn='!!:gs/“/"'
```

Neither seems to work and keeps giving me either the error

```
-bash: !!:gs/“/" : No such file or directory
```

or just:

> >

I must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: Weird.  That even makes sense to me as I don't know why mine wouldn't work.  So if I type “test“ and enter then run the alias it just returns the > line.  I think it sees the quote as the issue but not sure how to fix

Comment: I can now repro. Dunno why it was working before.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the order that command `!!` is evaluated.

Comment: BTW, `function foo() {` is a mix of POSIX and ksh function declaration syntax -- the POSIX version is `foo() {` with no `function`, the ksh version is `function foo {` with no `()`. It probably makes sense to use one or the other; I suggest the POSIX form, as bash's implementation of the ksh syntax doesn't provide the semantic benefits (such as automatically-local variables) present in the ksh releases it was adopted from. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85352/how-can-i-alias-sudo/85354#85354

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`!` does not work in functions or aliases. According to bash manual:

> History expansion is performed **immediately after a complete line is read**, before the shell breaks it into words.

You can use the builtin `fc` command:

```
[STEP 100] # echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.19(1)-release
[STEP 101] # alias damn='fc -s “=\" ”=\" '
[STEP 102] # echo “test”
“test”
[STEP 103] # damn
echo "test"
test
[STEP 104] #
```

---

For quick referecne, the following is output of `help fc`.

```
fc: fc [-e ename] [-lnr] [first] [last] or fc -s [OLD=NEW] [command]
    Display or execute commands from the history list.

    fc is used to list or edit and re-execute commands from the history list.
    FIRST and LAST can be numbers specifying the range, or FIRST can be a
    string, which means the most recent command beginning with that
    string.

    Options:
      -e ENAME  select which editor to use.  Default is FCEDIT, then EDITOR,
                then vi
      -l        list lines instead of editing
      -n        omit line numbers when listing
      -r        reverse the order of the lines (newest listed first)

|   With the `fc -s [OLD=NEW ...] [command]' format, COMMAND is
|   re-executed after the substitution OLD=NEW is performed.

    A useful alias to use with this is r='fc -s', so that typing `r cc'
    runs the last command beginning with `cc' and typing `r' re-executes
    the last command.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success or status of executed command; non-zero if an error occurs.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly more general solution using a bash function to wrap the `fc` call, if you want to do something to the string beyond substitution.

```
function damn() {
    # Capture the previous command.
    cmd=$(fc -ln -1)

    # Do whatever you want with cmd here
    cmd=$(echo $cmd | sed 's/[“”]/"/g')

    # Re-run the command
    eval $cmd
}
```

Comment: the magic thing about `fc -s` is that itself does not appear in the command history. with the `fc -s` solution in my answer, after `echo “test”` and `damn`, you press `↑` and will get `echo "test"`. thats to say you don't need to keep damn'ing. your solution would break this nice feature.

Comment: @pynexj, That's very interesting! I didn't realize that `fc -s` edits the history itself.

Comment: start to use `alias r='fc -s'` (as suggested in `help fc`) and u'll notice it. :)